# How do you determine if a Asp.net Scriptmanager is necessary on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

Is there a simple way to determine if there is a control on a page that requires a scriptmanager?  I am adding a scriptmanager to every page (which works great) in my page init, but it seems like there would be a better way than just forcing every page to have a scriptmanager. Maybe 1 in 4 pages have update panels, or some sort of extender. Or is it not much of an extra load and just not worry about it?

Comment: If you use updatePanel, then it's necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use inheritance to your advantage**. Create some sort of `ScriptManagerPageBase` class whose `PageInit` method invokes a new `ScriptManager`. For every page that requires your `ScriptManager`, such as using `UpdatePanel` control, simply have that page inherit from `ScriptManagerPageBase` and you'll get that functionality only when you need it, without having to duplicate code.

Comment: If I have a page that inherits from your "ScriptManagerPageBase" and a web user control (.ascx) that also has the need for a ScriptManager, when I host the myControl.ascx on yourPage.aspx won't they collide unless you use a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

In your master page (or a base page depending on your approach, I recommend master pages..) just add a scriptmanager. Unless needed it will not affect the page at runtime. Then add a scriptmanagerproxy to each page or control that needs a scriptmanager. At runtime the proxy will find the base or master manager and register any previously unregistered scripts. See [MSDN SCRIPTMANAGERPROXY discription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx)